# XAML Xamarin User Control in Page doesn't render content

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, user-controls, xamarin.forms

Hi I have a form with lots of duplicate code, I thought, why not split out to a user control so I have

Parent Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client.UI.Views.UserControls"
         x:Class="Client.UI.JobDetailPage"
         Title="Job Details">

  <ContentPage.Content>
     <ScrollView>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Label Text="BEFORE" x:Name="before" />
            <local:ViewItem ></local:ViewItem>
            <Label Text="AFTER" x:Name="after" />
         </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is my code we have a reference to local / View item.

This is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<View xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:controls="clr-namespace:Client.UI.Views.UserControls;assembly=Client.UI"
      x:Class="Client.UI.Views.UserControls.ViewItem">
     <Label Text="EXTERNAL PAGE" x:Name="ItemTitle" />
</View>
```

Code Behind

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Client.UI.Views.UserControls
{
   public partial class ViewItem : View
   {
        public ViewItem()
        {
              InitializeComponent();
        }
   }
}
```

When the app loads the page loads but no text is entered on the page. Any ideas why not ? Im so used to them working in ASP.NET web forms it really feels like im going backwards now

Comment: Could you post the code behind of your `ViewItem`?

Comment: added the code behind for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know the reason, but when I changed base class from `<View>` to `<Grid>` I was able to see text of label.

Comment: same here, i changed it to contentview and it worked for me also :)

Comment: The clean way to do it yourself instead of inheriting the functionality is implemented here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ContentView.cs